# Prepositions: "upon" vs. "after"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, formality

Despite having heard enough times already that *upon* is an archaic version of the *on* preposition, I'm still struggling to thoroughly understand its meaning and usage.

In the quoted sentence, wouldn't it make more sense to use *after*?

> Consider the possibility of activating accounts automatically upon a new dataset creation.

Is this just another way of expressing the thought, a more formal one?

Comment: 'Upon' is often a just more formal variant of 'on', though its use in certain subsenses might well be archaic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*After* means just that: at any time after the event. Using *after* would mean that once the new dataset had been created, the conditions are right for an account to be activated.

*Upon* indicates a simultaneous operation, "at the time of". See [ODO sense 8](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on) (*upon* redirects to *on*):

> **8** indicating the day or part of a day during which an event takes place:
>
> *reported on September 26*
>     *on a very hot evening in July*
>
> - at the time of:
>         *she was booed on arriving home*

The quoted sentence means

> Consider the possibility of activating accounts automatically at the time of a new dataset creation.

Comment: Andrew, would be correct to replace upon by during in the quoted sentece ?

Comment: No, don't use _during_. _During_ would suggest that one operation can't finish until the other has been completed. _Upon_ is a good word to use here, it conveys that one event is triggered by the other. As an example: _Upon hearing the punch line, he laughed._ He doesn't laugh _during_ the punch line, he laughs after. You could use _after_ in place of _upon_, but _upon_ suggests more of a quick reaction; _after_ could mean he had to think about the punch line first, before the laughter started.

Answer (score 0):

*Upon* may well refer to an action leading to/triggering another one immediately.

Comment: Propter hoc, not just always post hoc! I agree, Euclides, and this hasn't been mentioned before. But please add supporting (linked and attributed) reference/s; I suggest [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upon). Note that 'after' can also denote consequentiality ('After what Aloysius Elbon did to me, I’ll never trust him again'), but the default 'subsequent' sense is far more prevalent than with 'upon'.